# how to add alertProductNames to an incident in Azure Sentinel

Tags: azure, api, security, azure-sentinel

I'm using an API to create an incident in Azure Sentinel and it's working successfully but I want to add the alertproductnames with the API request to let it visible in azure sentinel.
this is the API URL:  PUT [https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/{subscriptionId}/resourceGroups/{resourceGroupName}/providers/Microsoft.OperationalInsights/workspaces/{workspaceName}/providers/Microsoft.SecurityInsights/incidents/{incidentId}?api-version=2022-12-01-preview](https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/%7BsubscriptionId%7D/resourceGroups/%7BresourceGroupName%7D/providers/Microsoft.OperationalInsights/workspaces/%7BworkspaceName%7D/providers/Microsoft.SecurityInsights/incidents/%7BincidentId%7D?api-version=2022-12-01-preview)

[image: this is the API request]
[image: this is the Request Body]
[image: this is the response image]

as you can see in image 3 the alertproductnames is empty, and I tried to add it to the request body but it didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to create alerts directly by adding them in the additonal properties of the Incident in Azure Sentinel, As Alerts needs to be created separately or gets triggered by an Incident.
Also, In the MS document:-[Incidents - Create Or Update - REST API (Azure Sentinel) | Microsoft Learn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/securityinsights/preview/incidents/create-or-update?tabs=HTTP#request-body) > The ***request body does not contain any property with** **alertProductNames**.*

I tried to create an Incident with ***alertProductName*** but it was not created, Refer below:-

**URI:-**

```http
https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/xxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xx-e2b6e97cb2a7/resourceGroups/sentinelrg/providers/Microsoft.OperationalInsights/workspaces/LoganalyticsWS/providers/Microsoft.SecurityInsights/incidents/id?api-version=2022-12-01-preview
```

**Body parameter:-**

```json
{

"properties": {

"title": "silicon Incident",

"description": "This is an silicon incident created using the Azure Sentinel API",

"severity": "Medium",

"status": "New",

"additionalData": {

"alertsCount": 1,

"bookmarksCount": 2,

"commentsCount": 2,

"alertProductNames": ["Azure Security Center"],

"tactics": [],

"techniques": ["T1189 - Drive-by-Compromise"]

}

  
  

}

}
```

**Output:-**

[image]

***To create Alerts with ProductName there's a different API refer below:-***

```http
PUT https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/{subscriptionId}/resourceGroups/{resourceGroupName}/providers/Microsoft.OperationalInsights/workspaces/{workspaceName}/providers/Microsoft.SecurityInsights/alertRules/{ruleId}?api-version=2022-12-01-preview
```

**Request Body:-**

```json
{

"kind": "Scheduled",

"properties": {

"displayName": "My scheduled rule",

"description": "An example for a scheduled rule",

"severity": "High",

"enabled": true,

"tactics": [

"Persistence",

"LateralMovement"

],

"techniques": [

"T1037",

"T1021"

],

"query": "Heartbeat",

"queryFrequency": "PT1H",

"queryPeriod": "P2DT1H30M",

"triggerOperator": "GreaterThan",

"triggerThreshold": 0,

"suppressionDuration": "PT1H",

"suppressionEnabled": false,

"eventGroupingSettings": {

"aggregationKind": "AlertPerResult"

},

"customDetails": {

"OperatingSystemName": "OSName",

"OperatingSystemType": "OSType"

}

}

}
```

**Output:-**

[image]

***References:-***

[Alert Rules - Create Or Update - REST API (Azure Sentinel) | Microsoft Learn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/securityinsights/preview/alert-rules/create-or-update?tabs=HTTP)

***List Alert by Incidents:-***

[Incidents - List Alerts - REST API (Azure Sentinel) | Microsoft Learn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/securityinsights/preview/incidents/list-alerts?tabs=HTTP)